# Android smack library subscription(not showing inbond or outbond notifications)

Tags: android, smack, asmack

I am working on an android chat application in which i am using smack library for instant messaging everything is working fine but the huge problem is in subscription.

How to send subscription notification to another user.

**Here is my code for sending subscription request:**

```
public void run() {
        /*runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {*/
                Roster roster = XMPPSmackConnection.getInstance().connection.getRoster();
                roster.setSubscriptionMode(Roster.SubscriptionMode.manual);
                try {
                    if(!_userName.contains("@"))
                        _userName=_userName+"@www.naijapings.net";

                    /*Presence presence = (Presence) packet;
                    Presence presence_request = new Presence(Presence.Type.subscribed);
                    presence_request.setTo(presence.getFrom());
                    presence_request.setType(Presence.Type.subscribed);
                    presence_request.setFrom("current_logged_in_user");
                    XMPPSmackConnection.getInstance().connection.sendPacket(presence_request);
                    roster.createEntry(presence.getFrom(), null, null);*/

                    /*Presence response = new Presence(Presence.Type.subscribe);
                    response.setTo(_userName);
                    XMPPSmackConnection.getInstance().connection.sendPacket(response);*/

                    //PROCESS TWO WAY COMMUNICATION
                    Presence response1 = new Presence(Presence.Type.subscribe);
                    response1.setTo(_userName);
                    XMPPSmackConnection.getInstance().connection.sendPacket(response1);
                    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////

                    //roster.createEntry(_userName, null, null);

                    /*roster.createEntry(_userName, _nickName, Friends);*/
                    //roster.createEntry(_tempUserName, null, null);
                    //roster.createEntry(_userName, _nickName, my_friends[]);
                    //addBuddy(_userName, _nickName, Friends);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    _progDailog.dismiss();
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                _progDailog.dismiss();
                successAlert("Buddy requested successfully");
            /*}
        });*/
```

The above code only create roster entry to other user's roster list but not showing subscription notification.

**Here is code for accepting subscription request:**

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    try {
                        Roster roster = XMPPSmackConnection.getInstance().connection.getRoster();
                        ///roster.setSubscriptionMode(Roster.SubscriptionMode.manual);
                        //Presence presence = roster.getPresence(_buddyUserName);
                        roster.setSubscriptionMode(Roster.SubscriptionMode.manual);
                        //Presence subscribed = new Presence(Presence.Type.subscribed);

                        Presence response = new Presence(Presence.Type.subscribed);
                        response.setTo(_buddyUserName);
                        XMPPSmackConnection.getInstance().connection.sendPacket(response);

                        /*response = new Presence(Presence.Type.subscribed);
                        response.setTo(_buddyUserName);
                        XMPPSmackConnection.getInstance().connection.sendPacket(response);*/

                        roster.createEntry(_buddyUserName, _nickNameEditText.getText().toString(), Friends);
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            });
```

Please suggest the exact scenario.

Comment: Hi All,Is there any solution for that ?

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I toiled hard at this for a couple of days and finally got things working. I have implemented it with a manual subscription mode (ie. user needs to accept another user's request manually).

The server keeps pushing subscribe request to the user (upon re-login) if the user hasn't sent a subscribed or unsubscribed back. So what you can do is save the incoming subscribe requests locally in a list and display that as a "friend request list" for manual accept/reject. If your application gets restarted (and hence re-connects to server), the server will push subscribe requests again.

This is how it works:

- User1 sends subscribe presence to User2.
- Roster entry gets automatically created in User1's roster (but not in User2's roster).
- User2 receives subscribe request from User1.
- User2 sends back a subscribed presence to User2 (User2 > User1 subscription complete).
- User2 checks if User1 is in User2's roster. User1 is not in User2's roster. User2 sends back a subscribe presence to User1.
- Roster entry gets automatically created in User2's roster.
- User1 receives subscribe presence from User2.
- User1 checks if User2 is in User1's roster. User2 is in User1's roster. User1 sends back a subscribed presence to User2 (User2 > User1 subscription complete).

  ```
          final Presence newPresence = (Presence) packet;
          final Presence.Type presenceType = newPresence.getType();
          final String fromId = newPresence.getFrom();
          final RosterEntry newEntry = getRoster().getEntry(fromId);

          if (presenceType == Presence.Type.subscribe)
          {
              //from new user
              if (newEntry == null)
              {
                  //save request locally for later accept/reject
                  //later accept will send back a subscribe & subscribed presence to user with fromId
                  //or accept immediately by sending back subscribe and unsubscribed right now
              }
              //from a user that previously accepted your request
              else
              {
                  //send back subscribed presence to user with fromId
              }
          }
  ```

Answer (score 0):

In order to receive subscription requests, you must:

1) Send presence:

```
<presence/>
```

2) Retrieve roster:

```
<iq type='get' id='roster1'>
  <query xmlns='jabber:iq:roster'/>
</iq>
```

First-time client writers are often surprised by the second one.

Comment: Thanks for replying Joe but i am doing the same if i am wrong somewhere then please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

you can not send subscription like that, do it this way:

```
 Presence subscription = new Presence(
               Presence.Type.subscribe);
       subscription.setTo(CurrentUser+"@reza-hp");
       subscription.setPriority(24);
       newp.setMode(Presence.Mode.available);
       connection.sendPacket(subscription);
```