# How to get "both" subscription type in openfire

Tags: java, android, openfire, smack, asmack

I am developing a simple android chat application.I am creating three users using asmack one by one
and also providing roster entries at creation time using 
**roster.createEntry()**; method

first of all i create

1.) user **111** with two roster entries **(JID=222@localhost.localdomain,JID=333@localhost.localdomain)**

then I create second user

2.)user **222** with two roster entries **(JID=111@localhost.localdomain,JID=333@localhost.localdomain)**

then I create user 333

3.) **333** with two roster entries **(JID=111@localhost.localdomain,JID=222@localhost.localdomain)**

here when I see roster entries of all three users then

**for user 111**

Subscription type for

```
                  JID=222@localhost.localdomain : "from"

                  JID=333@localhost.localdomain : "from"
```

**for user 222**

Subscription type for

```
                  JID=111@localhost.localdomain : "to"

                  JID=333@localhost.localdomain : "from"
```

**for user 333**

Subscription type for

```
                  JID=111@localhost.localdomain : "to"

                  JID=222@localhost.localdomain : "to"
```

So my problem is although all three users are online But the Presence is as follow

a.)  111 is "available" for 222 and 333

b.)  222 is "available" for only 333

c.)  333 is not available for any user

clearly this is due to "from" status .But I want that as all are online and all are added into each others roster list, so I need subscription status "both" for all three users roster list.So they will be "available" for each other if they are online.

Please help me how can I achieve this.

Comment: I think this link http://stackoverflow.com/a/6118119/1081355 might be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Its very simple. Open the openfire console open users tab.select a user.
open the user's roster.In roster select any entry and then open.edit properties of that particular entry.
In the edit window,  there is a option to set subscription, there a dropdown list will appear,  select "both".
Now u'll recieve roster presence in your application.

Comment: I wanted to achieve this using asmack not by admin console...Anyways I problem has been resolved now by Chetna..See comment..